# Run a Kubernetes Cron Job from OpenShift to call a REST endpoint Periodically

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, spring-batch, kubernetes-cronjob

I'm doing research on how to run a Spring Batch job on RedHat OpenShift as a Kubernetes Scheduled Job.
Steps have done,

1) Created a sample Spring Batch app that reads a .csv file that does simple processing and puts some data into in-memory h2 DB. The job launcher is called upon as a REST endpoint (**/load**). The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/samme4life/spring-batch-example). Please see the README file for the endpoint info.

2) Created the Docker Image and pushed into [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/samme4life/spring-batch/tags?page=1)

3) Deployed using that image to my OpenShift Online cluster as an [app](http://spring-batch-example-my-first-project.4b63.pro-ap-southeast-2.openshiftapps.com/health)

What I want to do is,

Run a Kubernetes Cron Job from OpenShift to call **/load** REST endpoint which launches the SpringBatch job periodically

Can someone please guide me here on how can I achieve this?

Thank you

Samme

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/

Comment: Do you know how to use `curl` to call your rest service in the cluster?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to curl your `/load` REST endpoint. 
Here's a way to do that:

**The Pod definition that I used as replacement for you application (for testing purposes):**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp-container
    image: mendhak/http-https-echo
```

I used this image because it sends various HTTP request properties back to client.

**Create a service for pod**:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp the selector
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80 #Port that service is available on
      targetPort: 80 #Port that app listens on
```

**Create a CronJob:**

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: curljob
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      name: curljob
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
        spec:
          containers:
          - command:
            - curl
            - http://myapp-service:80/load
            image: curlimages/curl
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            name: curljobt
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
  schedule: '*/1 * * * *'
```

**Alternatively you can use command to launch it:**

```
kubectl create cronjob --image curlimages/curl curljob -oyaml --schedule "*/1 * * * *" -- curl  http://myapp-service:80/load
```

When `"*/1 * * * *"` will specify how often this `CronJob` would run. I`ve set it up to run every one minute. 
You can see more about how to setup cron job [here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs) and [here](https://medium.com/swlh/the-power-of-kubernetes-cron-jobs-d7f550958de8)

**Here is the result of the kubectl logs from one of the job`s pod:**

```
{
  "path": "/load",
  "headers": {
    "host": "myapp-service",
    "user-agent": "curl/7.68.0-DEV",
    "accept": "*/*"
  },
  "method": "GET",
  "body": "",
  "fresh": false,
  "hostname": "myapp-service",
  "ip": "::ffff:192.168.197.19",
  "ips": [],
  "protocol": "http",
  "query": {},
  "subdomains": [],
  "xhr": false,
  "os": {
    "hostname": "myapp-pod"
```

As you can see the application receives `GET` request with path:  `/load`.

Let me know if that helps.